# What is the best way of terminating POSIX multi-threaded application which has critical section code?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

The application I am developing happens to be multi-threaded, and each thread has a critical section code. When user interrupts the application, I need to terminate the threads and save the execution state before terminating the application. To achieve this I coded some checks at random places in the thread function. Below is the minimal code that helps to understand the execution flow.

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct thread_data
{
    int quit;
    /* other data variables */
};

void* thread_func(void* data)
{

    for ( ; ; )
    {

        /* Non critical section code start */

        if (((struct thread_data*) data)->quit)   // checks at random places
            pthread_exit(NULL);

        /* end */

        if (((struct thread_data*) data)->quit)
            pthread_exit(NULL);

        /* Critical section code start */

            // Use data{} structure.

        /* end */

        if (((struct thread_data*) data)->quit)
                pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t sigmask;
    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGINT);

    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigmask, NULL);  // SIGINT is blocked by all the threads.


    struct thread_data* data = calloc(5, sizeof(struct thread_data));
    pthread_t tids[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)     // initialize the threads.
        pthread_create(tids + i, NULL, thread_func, (void*) (data + i));

    int signo;
    sigwait(&sigmask, &signo);  // wait for user interrupt.

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)     // terminate threads.
    {
        data[i].quit = 1;
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }

    /* Save the execution state */

        // Use data{} structure variable

    return 0;
}
```

But this method does not seem to be proficient, When the `thread_func` scales up, putting these checks at multiple places becomes tiresome. And a point to mention, I cant rely on signal disposition and calling `pthread_exit()` from signal handler as it is not `async-signal-safe function`. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: As I mentioned below, I've done similar for a commercial product. You probably want to split `data[i].quit` and `pthread_join` into separate `for` loops, so the threads can start cleanup in parallel. What you have to do can depend upon what's in the [various] critical sections (what syscalls--you'd need to field `EINTR` for `read`) and what cleanup needs to be done [I'm assuming it's more than merely `pthread_exit` (e.g.) close some files, release database locks, etc.].

Comment: Design so that regularly  saves the 'execution state'  in such a manner that the saved state is never invalid.  On quit, have the OS terminate the entire process.  Result: no fretting with thread termination, (something that is not guaranteed possible in a safe manner, save by the OS at process terminate), and resilence to Task-Manager 'End process', 'kill -9' and power failure.

Comment: Thats definitely a valid point. In the case of non catchable signals and power failures we loose the state, when the method I mentioned is adopted. But I feel the method you mentioned has a downside to it. The one we saved might not be a recent state. Its a tradeoff that we need to consider.

Comment: Indeed.  Unfortunately, the oft-repeated mantra of 'you must gracefully terminate all threads with user code' is often unrealistic and requires a massive alpha/beta code/debug/test effort to ensure reliability, often repeated for every release of app/OS/environment, that actually detracts from quality.  You deliver, but every time, it's "oh, I pray it shuts down for all my customers!".

Comment: You should probably post it as an answer. In some coding environments, it may be efficient to rely on OS routines, instead of developer going through all the pain.

Comment: @MohithReddy lol, if I cannot avoid the cargo-cult unrealistic mess of trying to explicitly terminate threads, I consider it a customer requirement error and/or utter design failure on my part:)  I don't post answers like this because it triggers the dozens of users who learned 'you must explicitly join threads' at Uni and have then spent years on premature stoptimization:)

Comment: @MartinJames: the regular saving of 'execution state' atomically wrt everything up to and including power-failure sounds tricky to me.  A method for that would surely be worthy of an answer ?  Of course, this introduces an overhead during normal execution, which I guess needs to be noted against the requirement.  But if the requirement is to stop gracefully under "normal" conditions, with minimum general overhead, that seems to point to controlled termination of all the threads ?  I haven't tried `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cancel()`... are they useful in this context ?

Comment: Well, how do you save the context?  Files?  Database tables?  Some server?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not what you're looking for and not really something groundbreaking. But to remove some text (because I agree that it looks a bit messy) at least declare a pointer instead of casting all the time.

```
void* thread_func(void* data)
{
    struct thread_data *d = (struct thread_data*) data;

    if(d->quit) pthread_exit(NULL);
```

If you're doing these checks a lot, this would make it a lot cleaner. You could even make it even more clean with `int *quit = &d->quit` but maybe that's overkill.

Or use a function or a macro:

```
void maybe_quit(int x) 
{
    if(x) pthread_exit(NULL);
}

#define MAYBE_QUIT do {  if (((struct thread_data*) data)->quit) \
                             pthread_exit(NULL); }               \
                   while(0)
```

Not really an innovative approach, but it would certainly make the code look cleaner.

When I have to do loads of error checking and I find the probability of ever having to debug or profile the exit check function to be very low, then I choose a macro. I think this is much easier to read:

```
void* thread_func(void* data)
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        /* Non critical section code start */

        MAYBE_QUIT;

        /* end */

        MAYBE_QUIT;

        /* Critical section code start */

            // Use data{} structure.

        /* end */

        MAYBE_QUIT;
    }
}
```

The difference is actually quite big when you read the code over and over again. The brain can quite fast learn to just ignore those capital letters.

Comment: No way I am going to cast it every time ! In my actual code-base i am using both the things you mentioned (macros and pointer) , but here in hurry i didnt code them.

Comment: I'm surprised you got DVed for this. I've had to do exactly this for a commercial grade product. What I did was very similar to what you came up with.

Comment: @CraigEstey Not to pick a fight with you. But if above comment is for me, then i am not one who did it.

Comment: @CraigEstey Not my DV, but it's a disgusting practice and almost certainly the wrong approach, but mostly that's on the OP's undeclared XY problem.